# figure out name of directory where file is placed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rake

I have for example this directory structure:

```
DIRECTORY_A/cat/myfile.txt
DIRECTORY_B/dog/myfile.txt
DIRECTORY_C/tiger/myfile.txt
```

you can see, in each directory I have the same file "myfile.txt". The "myfile.txt" is created by ruby script as shown below. Now I would like to put in myfile.txt the directory name where myfile.txt is located.

So for example, the:

```
 myfile.txt from "cat" directory should contain the string "cat"
 myfile.txt from "dog" directory should contain the string "dog"
 myfile.txt from "tiger" directory should contain the string "tiger"
```

Don't know how to to this. What to put instead the "????" as shown in my code:

```
def create_file
Dir['DIRECTORY_*/*/'].each do |dir|
  File.new File.join(dir, 'myfile.txt'), 'w+'
  Dir['DIRECTORY_*/*/myfile.txt'].each do |path|
    File.open(path,'w+') do |f| f.puts "????"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to extract the last directory name from the path. The easiest way of doing that is to use File.dirname and File.basename:

```
last_dir = File.basename(File.dirname(path))
File.open(path,'w+') { |f| f.puts lastdir }
```